# Why does this happen to Jenai in Bokeh?

Tags: plot-explanation, bokeh

WARNING: SPOILERS AHEAD!

In the film [Bokeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh_(film)), towards the end, Riley finds Jenai dead in a thermal pool, floating.

[image: Riley finds the dead body of Jenai in the thermal pool]

She shows no signs of a fight or other injuries. Suicide by suffocation or drowning is almost impossible, as Riley experiences himself.

**Why and how did she die?**